# Dos formularios en un mismo archivo

Tags: jquery, html

tengo un archivo index.php donde tengo dos panel-tab, cada un con su propio formulario,inputs y botones.
Manejo todos los evento con jquery en un archivo `script.js`.
Todo andaba bien con el segundo panel y sus elementos hasta que trate de crear el evento `$('#btnGuarda').on('click',function () {})`, que es un botón para guardar el formulario del primer tabpanel, y me sale este error al dar click en el botón:

```
jqxcore.js:7 Uncaught Error: Invalid Selector - #jqxgrid! Please, check whether the used ID or CSS Class name is correct.
```

(#jqxgrid es una grilla, pero da el mismo error despues con todos los elementos del segundo form)

alguna idea de a que se debe este error?

Comment: Obviamente tienes un problema con jQuery UI Widgets. ¿Ya te leíste la documentación por si estás obviando algo?

Comment: Prueba a crear el jquery sin la opción `.on`. Directamente '$('#btnGuarda').click(,function () {})'

Comment: De [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) en el centro de ayuda: "_Preguntas en busca de asistencia con la depuración ("¿por qué no funciona este código?") deben incluir cual es el comportamiento deseado, un problema o error específico **y el mínimo de código necesario para reproducirlo**_" (énfasis mío). Por favor, incluye el código en la pregunta

Answer (score 2):

¿Tienes importada más de una libreria de Jquery? Creo que se debe a que el objeto al que llamas no se corresponde con una libreria de jquery sino a un widget de jquery, en este caso parece ser JQGrid.

Puedes intentar utilizar una variable para evitar conflictos:

```
<script src="otra_libreria_jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Ahora en vez de llamar al listener mediante $, lo deberás hacer mediante $j, o el nombre que tu le proporciones a dicha variable.

```
$j('#btnGuarda').on('click',function () {})
```

Espero haberte podido ayudar, no sé si realmente estas importando otras librerias de jquery pero por el error parece que si.

Saludos.

Comment: gracias,funciono asi !

Comment: De Nada! Me alegro mucho que te haya servido, se agradece voto positivo y marcar la pregunta como solucion aceptada ;)